# How to get from MXP to BGY

Tags: public-transport, italy, transportation, milan

I am going on a business trip mid June

will be staying in Baveno, Italy for 3 days.

The company is going to transport us to MXP (Malpensa Airport) where everyone is flying back home.

I have other plans that I will travel through BGY (Milan Bergamo Airport)

My flight from BGY is at 4:00 pm

I found a company called OrioShuttle that has trips from MXP to BGY but has 2 trips a day
one at 9:15AM which is too early and the other at 3:30PM which is too late..

is there any other way to get from MXP to BGY?

Comment: You haven’t specified what time you will be able to leave from MXP, or the date (or at least the day of the week) but Google Maps lists quite a few options taking about 2 hours while a taxi should take about an hour.

Comment: Try google maps ("public transportation"), or rome2rio.com

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I have done train+bus, but there seem to be a shuttle now that goes from airport to airport. You can check it here [busradar](https://www.busradar.com/search/?From=Milan+Malpensa+Airport+%28MXP%29&To=Bergamo+Airport+%28BGY%29&When=2022-06-09&WhenReturn=&Passengers=1&ShowTrain=true&ShowTrain=false&ShowRidesharing=false).

Also, have you thought of Ubering or using the [Blablacar](https://www.blablacar.it/) platform? It is quite handy.